# How to sort a list by column?

Tags: python

I have a list of lists. How do I sort it by the price at index `[1]`?

```
lst = [["Apple", 12], ["Pear", 15], ["Peach", 10]]
new_lst = [["Pear", 15], ["Apple", 12], ["Peach", 10]]
```

Comment: `new_lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)`

Comment: See [**Key Functions**](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) section of the documentation's [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) to change the original `list`. With a `key`:

```py
>>> lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> lst
[['Peach', 10], ['Apple', 12], ['Pear', 15]]
>>> lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
>>> lst
[['Pear', 15], ['Apple', 12], ['Peach', 10]]
```

Note that you need to use `reverse=True` to be decending.

Or you can use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted) to assign the sorted `lst` to `new_lst`:

```py
>>> new_lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
>>> new_lst
[['Pear', 15], ['Apple', 12], ['Peach', 10]]
```